# Run selenium with Ant

Tags: ant, selenium

I looked on Google and here on stackoverflow, but couldn't find it.

I know it is possible, to start the selenium standalone server with an Ant script.

I'm trying to do it now for a half of a day.

The only thing what the script should do is:

- Start the selenium standalone sever
- Go to 1 web URL in Firefox
- shutdown

Comment: http://adam.goucher.ca/?p=423 ?

Comment: But where can I put the URL, because this is checking if the Server is up:   <http url="http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/index.html" errorsBeginAt="404"/> Another point is that this code is a little messy and is for testing of selenium scripts.. I only want to go to an URL.. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using? 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following solution to start the selenium standalone server with Ant:

```
<target name="selenium">
    <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="java -jar ${selenium.standalone} -htmlSuite ${selenium.browser} ${selenium.url} ${selenium.testsuite} ${selenium.result}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```